# Can I query for two different kinds with the same property?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

Is it possible to query for 2 different kinds that share the same property? Is the only way to do it is by polymorphism?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
ofy().load().types(Answer.class, Comment.class).filter("user", user);
```

is something like this exist?
I'm not sure I want to change the structure of the classes to make a superclass for these unrelated classes. It really should just by a short alias for making 2 queries in 1 trip to the datastore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to query for two different entity kinds in a single datastore call. Each entity kind becomes a part of a key for each entity, and these keys are indexed. Each query works with a specific index tied to one entity kind. So you have to use two different queries if you want to find/retrieve two different kinds of entities.